# WinPcap: pcap_open does not return

Tags: matlab, winpcap

I tried this example for opening an adapter and capturing packets:

https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut3.html

It prints the adapter list but after that pcap_open does not
return and locks Matlab. I have to quit and restart Matlab to continue.

If I do not pass the correct devicename to pcap_open but
something like "dummy", I get the correct error message.

Windump and WireShark function perfectly, so the installed WinPcap 4.1.3
is o.k.

I use Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C) on Windows 10 and compile 
in Matlab with:

```
mex -I.\WinPcap_developers_pack\Include .\WinPcap_developers_pack\Lib\x64\wpcap.lib ReadPackets.c
```

The defines and includes are:

```
#define WIN32 // otherwise the Unix branch is selected in pcap.h
#define HAVE_REMOTE // needed according to Q-23 of the WinPcap FAQ

#include "mex.h" // needed for Matlab
#include "pcap.h" // straight from this WinPcap example
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please use the code-tags to improve the readability of your post.

Comment: DO you have configured the timeout?

Comment: Yes, it is set to 5000 ms.

Comment: MAybe you can attach with a debugger and look for any WaitForMultibleObjects are there? Seems to be blocked somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It only seemed like pcap_open did not return. Everything worked fine - invisibly. The cause was that stdout is buffered heavily so print statements for debugging did print only at the program's end.

The next statement was eventually used to flush and reveal what was going on:

```
mexEvalString("pause(0.01);");
```

The standard fflush and _flushall have no effect in mex-files.